# result display in the new window

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

i have created a button which calculates sum value . after calculation i want to display my result in the new window like pop up window .along with other selected value in the drop box. here is my code.

```
 function CalCost(a)
   {
       var area = a;

             var Total_Cost = 0;

             var max = 100;

                 if(a == 1)
                 {
                       J = 40;
                       D = 15;
                       E = 900;
                       P = 75;
                       L = 50;
                       E = 5;
                       M = 16;
                       Pi =8;
                       Pr = 34;
                       Ir = 52;
                       W = 42;
                       RK = 25;
                       Sp = 7;
                      Total_Cost = J+D+E+P+L+E+M+Pi+Pr+Ir+W+RK+Sp;
                 }                 
         }
```

Comment: what is the question? :)

Comment: after calculation i want to dispaly results in new window. i am asking how to create a pop window to display function's result

Comment: you can use a hidden div, and show it when you parse the data, or you can use a framework

Comment: how can i use hidden div.  after clicking a button i want to diplay info window. it is like report

Comment: as @user7923798 said, try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it , also I presume you are looking for a new window and not a modal or pop up window. For that you can use `window.open` & update the value there

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write(Total_Cost);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/w5fh6smx/)

**EDIT**

First create a dom for modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id ='calValue'></p> // calculated value will be show here
  </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Check demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/w5fh6smx/1/)

Comment: i want to dispaly resutls in pop up window. kindly enlightened my about modal

Comment: thanks it helps. i want it like generating a report. like when i click on button   <input id="Cost" name="sum" type="button" value="Cost Calculation" onclick= CalCost(document.getElementById('area).value); it calculate cost and then shows results in the pop up window or modal. and i also want to add some other attributes

Comment: when i use the same button to calculate and display modal. modal does not display.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: if i want to add all the variable i have used to calculate the sum, display on the form along total cost.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a hidden div in your HTML and set absolute position to div, Show/Hide it on click using JavaScript "style.display" property.

To show div use

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "";
```

To hide div

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
```

Or you can use JQuery dialog https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated